# How node.js save variables outside an async operation for accessing inside it's callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, promise

Refer to the example code below, i declare a variable outside a promise/Async call and it's value assign by each request when they reach to this line, now my question is, if many requests came and reach to when it reach to the `console.log(something);` line at the same time:

1. node.js treat each request like an object and keep `something` value specific to each one or it just print the last one's value?
2. if it print the last one, how can i solve the problem and keep `something` specific to each request?

---

```
router.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  var something = req["request's specific data"];

  anAsyncCall(something2).then(function(data) {
    //value of something?
    console.log(something);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables declared with the `var` keyword are locally scoped to the function they are declared in.

Each invocation of the function creates a new scope and a new variable within that scope.

```js
function myFunction(myValue) {
    var copyOfMyValue = myValue; // For demonstration purposes. Function arguments are the same as variables declared with var
    function showMyValue() {
        console.log(copyOfMyValue);
    }
    return showMyValue;
}

setTimeout(myFunction(1), 100);
setTimeout(myFunction(2), 90);
setTimeout(myFunction(3), 80);
setTimeout(myFunction(4), 70);
setTimeout(myFunction(5), 60);
```

This is standard JavaScript behavior and nothing specific to Node.JS.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: It's exclusive to each request AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

`var something` is declared locally within the function `function(req, res)`

Each URL call to `/test` will create a new instance of `something` and each will be local (and independant) to each request.

So your answers are:

1. node.js treat each request like an object and keep something value specific to each one or it just print the last one's value?

**Answer: it will be kept 'specific'**

2. if it print the last one, how can i solve the problem and keep something specific to each request?

**Answer: not relevant, because of 1. ;-)**